# SonarQube Delete all project

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-web

Does any one know how to delete all project in SonarQube5.6 ?
I login to admin  and  go to project manage page , It just delete only 50 and can show more only 50.
Thank you.

Comment: You could start with a new database...

Comment: thanks :D , but if i use default database.It has other way to delete ?

Comment: If you are using the default database you could stop SonarQube and delete all database files and start again; the database will be created. Do not use this configuration in a production environment. See also the documentation in the configuration file.

Comment: thank you @Jeroen Heier ,just use "sonar stop" for stop sonarQube? and how can i delete all files?

Comment: I you are installed SonarQube as a windowsservice use \bin<platform>\StopNTService.bat (execute as admin). Then remove all files in \data except for README.txt. Use \bin\<platform>\StartNTService to start SonarQube again. Then you should have a brand new environment (no projects, alle settings configured as default).